# PopupMenu avoid dismiss on click of Keyboard

Tags: android

I'm facing an issue without being able to find an answer. I have an editText with a TextWatcher to find a list of results in a database. I display the result in a PopupMenu. It looks like this :

[image]

```
final List<SearchResult> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();

    final PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), binding.bottomSheetWriteNews.editTextNewsSubCategory);
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            binding
                    .bottomSheetWriteNews
                    .editTextNewsSubCategory
                    .setText(item.getTitle());

            return false;
        }
    });


    final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    binding.bottomSheetWriteNews.editTextNewsSubCategory.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            searchResults.clear();
            menu.getMenu().clear();

            RealmResults<SubCategory> subCategoriesResult = realm.where(SubCategory.class).contains("name", s.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
            for(SubCategory subCategory : subCategoriesResult) {
                searchResults.add(new SearchResult(subCategory.getId(), subCategory.getName(), false));
                menu.getMenu().add(subCategory.getName());
            }
            menu.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

My issue is every-time I click on the Keyboard the PopupMenu is dismiss instead of typing the character I wanted. That's annoying and unusable for users. I want the click on keyboard to not dismiss the PopupMenu. I know that in the official documentation it's written `Touching outside of the popup will dismiss it`, but I'm using Google Keep, and they have the same feature (typing text display a PopupMenu to filter results) without my issue.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using popup menu you can use

> spinner or (list view or recycler view )

and do `notifyDataSetChanged().`

So that the layout won't get piling(off and on)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to my own answer after I found an alternative solution with a coworker. There is a specific EditText named [autoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) which can take an ArrayAdapter. And it will do the search for you. Here is how I implemented it :

```
final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<SubCategory> subCategoriesResult = realm.where(SubCategory.class).findAll();
    List<String> categoryName = new ArrayList<>();
    for(SubCategory subCategory : subCategoriesResult) {
        categoryName.add(subCategory.getName());
    }
    String[] stringArray = categoryName.toArray(new String[0]);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, stringArray);
    binding.bottomSheetWriteNews.autoCompleteTextViewNewsSubCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And nothing more ! After typing two characters the list of result will show as a PopupMenu.

In any case, if someone has a solution to avoid dismiss after clicking on keyboard when a PopupMenu is showed, I'm interested. Thanks !